How can I resolve the Lazypredict error on a visual-studio-code using python on anaconda platform?

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[90], line 3
1 #%pip install -r requirements.txt
2 import lazypredict
----> 3 from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
File c:\Users\w23052945\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\lazypredict\Supervised.py:98
89 # CLASSIFIERS.append(('CatBoostClassifier',catboost.CatBoostClassifier))
91 numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
92     steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())]
93 )
95 categorical_transformer_low = Pipeline(
96     steps=[
97         ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="missing")),
---> 98         ("encoding", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse=False)),
99     ]
100 )
102 categorical_transformer_high = Pipeline(
103     steps=[
104         ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="missing")),
(...)
107     ]
108 )
111 # Helper function
TypeError: OneHotEncoder.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sparse'
import lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is likely because the version of scikit-learn you're using does not support this argument.
You could try to upgrade scikit-learn by the following command in your terminal:
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn


LazyPredict is providing the wrong parameter name to sklearn OneHotEncoder, simply change sparse by sparse_output in Supervised.py   (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)
On the other hand, you can always contribute to the project https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict
